# batch "start" command does not work... windows opens.. but nothing runs

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
set T=0
ECHO OFF

title loop script - close to stop loop

:ping


IF  %T%==3000 (


ECHO ON
ECHO Loop complete... repeat.
ECHO OFF
set T=0

start "%0\..\attack\dos.bat"    <----- Not working....

) ELSE (

SET /A T = %T% + 1

)


goto ping
```

If you wonder, this is a Loop script which performs an Action every 3 seconds.

My Problem: the "start" command which starts the dos.bat does not work. It opens a new command window called "dos.bat" but its empty and the code in the dos.bat is not running.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know that it's not running? If you put just `notepad.exe` inside that file, don't Notepad windows open?

Comment: well... i can replace dos.bat with any name Ex: "derp.bat" etc...  it always opens an empty command window... and i know its not running because i dont see any echos...

Answer (score 1):

Command `start` interprets first double quoted parameter as **title** for the new command prompt window. I don't really understand why you use command `start` and not command `call`, but here is your batch code in a manner which should work.

```
@echo off
set "T=0"
title loop script - close to stop loop
:ping
if %T%==3000 (
    echo on
    echo Loop complete... repeat.
    echo off
    set "T=0"
    start "My bad script attacking websites!" "%~dp0..\attack\dos.bat"
) else (
    set /A T+=1
)
goto ping
```

Comment: im using start because i want to open multiple window to the same time... using call it overwrites your actual window...